# I have a smart contract in Ethereum. Is there a way to migrate it over to Cardano?

Tags: plutus, nft, ada, smart-contract

I have a smart contract for an NFT in Ethereum and I'd like to put it in the Cardano eco system as well. How can I do that? Is there any 'smart contract bridge' through which I can port it over?

Comment: Since I don't know your Smart Contract I am sorry if I am stating the obvious: you know you don't need a smart contract for minting NFT on Cardano, right?

Comment: Yes. My requirement is that - I need to deploy an NFT collection which will be generated programmatically. I guess my thoughts were to somehow connect it to the Cardano eco system such that the public can view what's in it to be transparent. My assumption was that such a capability would require programmability over a zero code solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either rewrite your smart contract in Plutus (haskell) or you can wait for the ERC20 Converter. I haven't heard much about it lately, but the [latest status update (October)](https://roadmap.cardano.org/en/status-updates/2021-10/) shows there is progress towards a public testnet deployment:

> The team is making continued progress towards public testnet deployment as they parallel track some additional mainnet optimizations. DevOps has completed the first round of testing on an internal environment and is now addressing some fixes prior to redeployment. Once the fixes are confirmed, SingularityNET will do additional testing prior to determining a confirmed release date.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: A query on the second part of the suggestion: NFTs are minted using the ERC721 protocol right? So does an ERC20 converter help in moving NFT issued on the Ethereum network to Cardano eco system? TBH I doubt it.
My main goal to do this is to save gas fees and eventually sell it off via CNFT platform. Re-minting all of it again seems tedious atm.

Comment: Just a couple of weeks ago there was an announcement about IOHK and Bondly partnering up to create a bridge for Ethereum based NFTs to move them over to Cardano.

https://bondlyfinance.medium.com/io-global-and-bondly-announce-development-of-bridge-from-ethereum-to-cardano-networks-3a829e56b5e9